# Datatables server side - How to manipulate rows/tr parameters

Tags: datatables

I have a server-side datatable. Data is pulled from a json.

```
<table id=xxx>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#xxx').DataTable({
    "serverSide\": true,
    "ajax\": \"ss_ajax.cgi\",
    "deferRender\": true
  });
});
</script>
```

Table is properly rendered and datatable adds the respective tbody, tr and tds.

Now, I need to add/inject custom parameters and an onclick event to the tbody tr. I tried to add a tr inside the data element inside the ajax but no luck.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I appreciate.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] so that we can see your code and recreate your specific problem.

Comment: What _is_ the specific problem (what does "no luck" really mean)? What errors do you get in the browser console? What does "add a tr inside the data element" mean? What data element are you referring to? What would a successful outcome actually look like?

Comment: Appreciate Andrew, I didn't want to bother with all the details. All I need to understand is how to add custom parameters and onclick events to the rows that the datatable renders in the tbody. <tr rcode="$rcode" onclick="document.index.rcode.value='$rcode';">

Comment: OK - understood, thank you for the update. There are numerous Stack Overflow questions, with answers which already cover this.

Comment: Can you kindly point me to one? I did search but could only find misleading answers. I appreciate your time.

Comment: I can't - because I would probably just direct you to those same misleading answers. I don't want to waste your time.